# 3D plot of the residual sum of squares in linear regression

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, least-squares

I'm trying to reproduce Figure 3.2 from the book [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/). Figure describes 3D plot of the residual sum of squares (RSS) on the [Advertising data](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv), using `Sales` as the response and `TV` as the predictor variable for a number of values for $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$.

[image]

My code is pasted below:

```
# Read data from URL
data <- read.csv("http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv")
# Extract TV variable
X <- data[, 2]
# Prediction variable with ones in the first column
X <- cbind(1, X)
# Prediction variable
y <- data$Sales

# Define function for RSS
MyRss <- function(beta0, beta1) {
  b <- c(beta0, beta1)
  rss <- t(y - X %*% b) %*% (y - X %*% b)
  return(rss)
}
```

Now I calculate RSS value for each combination of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ and plot it with `persp()` function:

```
b0 <- seq(5, 9, 0.01)
b1 <- seq(0.03, 0.06, 0.001)
z <- outer(b0, b1, function(x,y) mapply(MyRss, x, y))
persp(x = b0, y = b1, z = z)
```

The derived plot is pasted below:

[image]

I don't know where my code fails. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Why do you think your code fails? Probably, you just have to adjust `b0` and `b1` and turn the plot a bit. I don't think perspective pots are very useful. A contour plot might be a better choice.

Comment: You are right. I just need to adjust limits.

Comment: @Andrej Please, could you include the solution to your question? It could help others like me trying to replicate that figure. Thanks.